# XGBoost Classification, Different AUC score for XGBClassifier vs xgb.train Even After Rounding Prediction Probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

it seems that XGBClassifier is a wrapper over `xgb.train`. I was trying to train a binary classifier using `xgb.train` and `"objective": "binary:logistic"`.

It seems that using `xgb.train` followed by `.predict()` returns the prediction probabilities which we can round to either 0 or 1 for the classification (based on an answer I saw in another stackover question, xgb.train results probabilities which we need to round off to get the actual classification prediction)

So if we have binary classification, we need to round off <0.5 ==> class 0 and >0.5 ==> class 1?

But what if it is multiclass? Then we assume a uniform distribution for and split it evenly? e.g. 3 class ==> 0~1/3, 1/3~2/3, 2/3~1?

What is the right way to use `xgb.train` as a classifier?

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

data = np.random.rand(50,10) # 50 entities, each contains 10 features
label = np.random.randint(2, size=50) # binary target

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=label)
param = {'max_depth':3, 'eta':0.1, 'silent':1, 'tree_method':'hist','objective':'binary:logistic', 'seed':42}
num_round = 100  # same as number of estimator
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain, num_round)
trainres = bst.predict(dtrain)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, objective='binary:logistic', tree_method='hist', eta=0.1, max_depth=3, enable_categorical=True, seed=42)
model = model.fit(data,label)
fitres = model.predict(data)

# Compare classification
print(all([round(x) for x in trainres] == fitres))


# Compare probabilities. Predict proba gives prob for class 0 and 1, so take x[1]
print(all([x[1] for x in model.predict_proba(data)] == trainres))
```

Output:

```
True

True
```

Comment: Not sure why you are rounding the predictions here - ROC & AUC take as input raw probabilities of the predicted data, and not hard labels 0/1; could you possibly post a [mre] using some open dataset (say from scikit-learn)? Plus, there is a `random_state` parameter for the classifier, which you do not set, and might very well lead to the outputs being different due to the randomness inherent in the algorithm.

Comment: Hi @deseartnaut, thanks for the comment! I have edited the question to set a reproducible example and also set the seed param to the same value.